# CoreService: Upload image to Tridion fails sometimes. Unable to open uploaded file

Tags: c#

I am trying to upload an image to Tridion using CoreService.
Upload is done using streamClient.UploadBinaryContent.

After upload I want to create an MultiMedia component from it.
The code works fine on our staging environment.
On pro environment the code only works on each third try (basically a 33% chance of success).

Giving the error :"Invalid value for property 'BinaryContent'. Unable to open uploaded file: C:\Windows\TEMP\tmp8EFA.jpg" when I try to save the MultiMedia Component.

My questions are:

- How I can check if the upload was successfull?
- What am I doing wrong?
- Am I closing any streams too early?
- Should I place a sleep timer somewhere to wait until the upload finshed?

Note: I do not have access to Tridion administration to check any settings.

I already included several catches and loops to retry, but I stripped these from the code snippet below.

```
string tempLocation = "";
        using (StreamUploadClient streamClient = GetNewUploadClient()) 
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    tempLocation = streamClient.UploadBinaryContent(fileInfo.Name.ToLower(), objfilestream);
                    objfilestream.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (streamClient.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    streamClient.Abort(); //never ended up in here
                else
                    streamClient.Close();
            }
        }

        ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions() { LoadFlags = LoadFlags.Expanded };
        BinaryContentData binaryContent = new BinaryContentData();
        binaryContent.UploadFromFile = tempLocation;
        binaryContent.Filename = fileInfo.Name.ToLower();
        binaryContent.MultimediaType = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData() { IdRef = GetMultimediaTypeId(fileInfo.Extension) }; //typeids should be correct as it is working sometimes
        multimediaComponent.BinaryContent = binaryContent;

        IdentifiableObjectData savedComponent = null;
        try
            {
                savedComponent = GetNewCoreService().Save(multimediaComponent, readOptions); //this one fails
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { /* log and do a loop */ }
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks & bye

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a load balancer between your client and the Core Service?
That may cause the problem: if the load balancer sends the upload request to another CM backend server than the subsequent Save request, the stream is uploaded to a local temporary file on a different CM server than the one that handles the Save request (so that temporary file doesn't exist there).
This is a known limitation in the current Core Service upload implementation (unfortunately you can't specify a file location for the temporary files, so you can't use an UNC location accessible by all CM backend servers).

Comment: Thats what I am currently looking into. I will update the question as soon as I have a result.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that you close the stream inside your `using` statement. Strictly speaking you shouldn't do it as it will be closed by the `using` statement.

Looking at exception it seems that it's failing on saving component, not on uploading binary. I would check that binary is correct at "C:\Windows\TEMP\tmp8EFA.jpg" on CM server. Does, retry of `Save` operation help? If so - it's IO problem and you could try to troubleshoot it with ProcMon, for instance.

Take a look at: http://amarchuk.blogspot.nl/2011/11/creating-multimedia-component-through.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot but are you running a virus scanner on the CM server? I've seen these kinds of problems where an antivirus product was blocking the upload for no apparent reason...

Other long shots:

- outscaling? Are you running 3 WebGUI servers?
- timeouts or size limitations? Does the size of the image make any difference?
- IO issues? is the temp folder full of files (slows down directory enumerations) or the disk nearly full?
- concurrency issues? Is your streamclient closing a trigger for the CM server to delete the temp file and does it come to soon?